# Normal extension of given degree of a number field

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $n>1$ be a natural number.

> **Question.** Let $K$ be a number field, and let $S\subset V_f(K)$ be a finite set of finite (non-archimedean) places of $K$.
> Does there exist a *normal* extension $L/K$ of degree $n$ such that for all places $v\in S$, the tensor product
> $L\otimes_K K_v$ is a field
> (a normal extension of $K_v$ of degree $n$)? Here $K_v$ denotes the completion of $K$ at $v$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: OK, I have removed the 2nd question.